# why regional persistent disk can be created from a snapshot but not an image in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In The GCP documentation , I could see  **regional persistent disk  can be created  from a snapshot but not from image in GCP** , why only from snapshot not from image ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Public [ISSUE](https://issuetracker.google.com/146534399) for your question. Feel free to post there should you have any additional comments or concerns regarding the issue.

Comment: Your issue link is broken.

Comment: It's seems ok now.